# Webview within a scroll view loading html wrongly on first load

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have done my research and I haven't found a suitable question for my problem. I got a WebView inside a ScrollView, and once I get the HTML from my service, I call

```
myWv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,myHtml,"text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Nothing special there. The problem I'm having is that, when I run my Application in a 4.4.2 Android tablet, the WebView loads the HTML with the words split in lines, eg:

```
This
is
my
sentense
```

And after a second it renders the HTML correctly but the ScrollView's scroll is as big as the number of lines it rendered before loading the HTML correctly. I have tested in 3 different smartphones and everything is fine, only in the tablet it seems to happen, probably due to some performance issue since my HTML is huge.

Does any of you have have had this problem before and knows how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wondering if there's any particular reason the `WebView` needs to be inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: It does because the HTML is huge

Comment: My understanding is that `WebView` is capable of scrolling its content itself, so for what it's worth you may be able to do without the `ScrollView`. (Apologies if I've missed something)

Comment: I removed the scroll view and it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extend WebViewClient. And in your custom WebViewClient overload the method onPageFinished.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // If you create a listener, here you can trigger it
    // you can show the webview here as it will be already measured.
}
```

If you show the webview when the page is already entirely loaded there won't be any ugly animation.

Comment: I have tried that and I get the same outcome. I only make the webview visible onPageFinished and still I get the same problem

Comment: No. I just load the webview when I get the content from the previous activity